# Checking if list item of index exists in another list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list which contain coordinates of lines as array. When I use list methods some works some doesn't.

```
for line1 in line2:
    print(line2.index(line1))          # doesn't work
    print(line2[2])                    # works 
    line2.pop(0)                       # works
    line2.remove(line1)                # doesn't work
    if line1 in line2:                 #doesn't work 
        print('line exist')

    # line2 is shown here because I cannot show it properly else where.
    [
        array([[696, 188, 696,   0]], dtype=int32), 
        array([[  2, 192,   2,   0]], dtype=int32), 
        array([[460, 192, 460,   0]], dtype=int32),
        array([[699, 190, 699,   0]], dtype=int32), 
        array([[802, 192, 802,   0]], dtype=int32),
        array([[462, 180, 462,   0]], dtype=int32)
    ]
```

Basically I want to check if a line exist in list named line2 if yes then find its index and remove it.

Comment: your code is unreadable. please indent it properly

Comment: Now check if its ok.

Comment: You should not try to delete an element from a list while iterating through it. What is your exact usecase?

Comment: Are those `numpy` arrays?

Comment: I have an other list named line3=line2 and I'm removing from it line3 while iterating through  line2.

Comment: You might need `deepcopy` since you have a nested list. `line3` = `line2` will have both referencing the same object.

Comment: how can I do that

Comment: Try `import copy` then `line2_copy = copy.deepcopy(line2)` - [Shallow and Deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#module-copy) - if you are using `numpy` arrays things are different than normal lists operations.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a list of values to index function. That's why it is confused which index to pick. You need to find the indices of elements which need to be removed from your list.

```
lines_to_remove_indices = []
for i, line1 in enumerate(line2):
    if line1.all() in line2:                 #will work 
        print('line exist')
        lines_to_remove_indices.append(i)
for i, line in enumerate(line2):
    if not i in lines_to_remove_indices:
        new_list.append(line)
```

Comment: what's the output you are getting?

Comment: It looks something like this                                                 if line1.all() in line2:                 #will work  

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: this line `if line1.all() in line2:` just make sures that line1 is successfully removed. Just comment it. You'll get `[]` list at end as all entries have been removed

Comment: I have comment out  the removing line  to check to if line.all() in line2 works or not

Comment: More successful way is to create a new list with those elements you want to keep.

Comment: my code is structured in the way that I have to remove item which are extras. I can not create a new list because it destroys the logic the code is working on.

Comment: if some way i can get index of item then i can remove it using pop.

Comment: You cannot remove element while iterating to a list. You need to get indices first then create a new list in which those elements are not included

Comment: I have done the same . I have a list name line3 which is equal to line2 . from line3 I'm removing items I'm using line2 only for iterating.

Comment: No I having the same Issue.

Comment: i am unable to upload the code right now I am getting a warning I will upload it an hour later

Answer (score 0):

`line2.pop(0)` will eliminate the item and so `line2.remove(line1)` will throw an error. If you comment them both out, you'll get down to the "line exist" print-statement:

```
for line1 in line2:
    print(line2.index(line1))          # doesn't work
    print(line2[2])                    # works 
    #line2.pop(0)                       # works
    #line2.remove(line1)                # doesn't work
    if line1 in line2:                 #doesn't work 
        print('line exist')
```

Comment: if line_1 in line2:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()